# Storyboards, removing subviews & adding them again later with the design constrains preserved

Tags: ios, constraints, uistoryboard, subview

Ok, I have two complex (UI-wise) UIViewControllers. They share a [super] viewcontroller between them.

Some subviews (buttons, labels, uiviews) are to appear and disappear based on a series of remote events.

What I want to do is (well, already have), design the UI for both inside one of my storyboards, and then, in viewWillLayoutSubviews or viewDidLayoutSubviews, initially remove some visual elements from the view.

BUT, these are to be added again later during the lifecycle of the viewcontroller.

so, how can I design my view, initially [subview removeFromSuperview]; and then add these elements *with the constrains I added during design*

Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but since I'm going to be removingFrom and addSubview, I will have to make each of these IBOutlets strong (otherwise they will be lost after removeFromSubview, right?)

anyhow, any help / pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to save the constraints manually by looping through the superview's constraints (and the constraints of the view you're removing also, if they have size constraints). You can do that something like this,

```
-(void)saveConstraintsForView:(UIView *) viewToRemove {
    for (NSLayoutConstraint *con in self.view.constraints) {
        if ([con.firstItem isEqual:viewToRemove] || [con.secondItem isEqual:viewToRemove]) {
            [self.constraintArray addObject:con];
        }
    }
}
```

And, yes, the IBOutlets for the views will have to be strong so they won't be deallocated when they are removed from their superview.

Comment: actually, for the constrains, before removal, I'm trying NSArray *constrains=[subViews constrains]; (the array is actually an instance variable). What I'm wondering is how I can add them AGAIN.

Comment: What is "[subViews constrains]" doing? Is that getting constraints from the superview?

Comment: it's an UIView method: - (NSArray *)constraints. Description: 
Returns the constraints held by the view.

Comment: @dhomes, but that will give you all the constraints for the view, so  unless you're going to be removing all the constraints for your view, you'll still have to loop through them to only remove the ones you want.

Comment: THANKS FOR THE TIP! been doing networking today, I'll test your solution and mark it as the proper answer very soon.

Comment: @rdelmar how to add them again ?